# Change labels according to table td inputs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, save, label

**Let me first explain** why I need to do this so that it makes sense. On the page there are various labels/titles for sections. Users might want to name these titles something else or use a different language. Instead of "Color" maybe "Hue". There is a table holding the information for the label and the section information. So, "color" and "red", and so on.

**What I need is** when the user changes a label input field in the table and clicks save - for the corresponding label(s) on the page to change. Within the table, the first column is the id of the matching label and also the class of the corresponding input. http://jsfiddle.net/NNpCB/4/

**jQuery**

```
// dynamically give table text inputs, with correct label classes
var valueCol = $("table#ruleTable tr td:nth-child(2)");
valueCol.html(function(){
    return '<input value="' + $(this).text() + '" class="' + $(this).prev().text() + '" />';
});

// save new label text
$('.saveLbl').click(function () {
    // for each input that was changed, find the corresponding label(s) and change the label text
    // the input .class matches the label #id
});
```

**HTML**

```
<label id="lblcolor">Colors</label>
<ul>
    <li>Red</li>
    <li>Blue</li>
    <li>Yellow</li>
</ul>    

<label id="lblshape">Shapes</label>
<ul>
    <li>Square</li>
    <li>Circle</li>
    <li>Rectangle</li>
</ul> 
<br /><br />
<table id="ruleTable" border='1' cellpadding='15'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Label</th>
            <th>Display Value</th>
            <th>Language</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>lblcolor</td>
            <td>Colors</td>
            <td>ENG</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>lblshape</td>
            <td>Shapes</td>
            <td>ENG</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>        
</table>
<br /><br />
<button class='saveLbl'>Save</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code : ( http://jsfiddle.net/W4k7W/ )

```
 $('.saveLbl').click(function () {
    // for each input that was changed, find the corresponding label and change the label text
    // the input .class matches the label #id
    var rows=$("#ruleTable tbody").children();
    for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
        var rowKids = $(rows[i]).children();
        var labelClass=$(rowKids[0]).text();
        var value=$($(rowKids[1]).children()[0]).val(); // <--- rowKids[1] is the td , its first child is the input row 
        $("#"+labelClass).text(value);
    }
});
```